# Canvas & graphics context - how to change the shape of the brush

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, uigraphicscontext

When I have a GraphicsContext object and am using it to draw on a canvas using:

```
scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
        graphicsContext.beginPath();
        graphicsContext.lineTo(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    });

    scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
        graphicsContext.lineTo(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
        graphicsContext.stroke();
    });
```

the shape its drawing with is a square, ie, if I just click and don't move the mouse a square will appear. How do I change this to a circle?

Comment: @James_D setting the line cap to ROUND and lowering the miter limit seems to have done it. Thanks.

Comment: If @James_D's answer helped you, consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to it. This helps people looking for similar solutions know that this has an answer that works, and it gives a little boost to James_D's reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the shape of the end of a line with

```
graphicsContext.setLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
```

You might also want to change the miter limit, which (as I understand it) changes the behavior of how lines are rendered around sharp corners.

```
graphicsContext.setMiterLimit(1);
```

See the [documentation for stroke attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#strk-attr).